# Disable sound output for WebView

Tags: cocoa, macos, webview

Is there any way how to mute all sounds in WebView? With Mac SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's possible to mute sound coming from a `WebView`, at least not with public APIs. You can [control the system audio volume via Core Audio](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1016/_index.html), but this is global.